# jQuery tab slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all, i am trying to find a good example of this type of slider [HERE](http://www.adamscrap.com/). I can not seem to find the "official" name for it so i really can't search for it. The effect that i am trying to find is that of the triangle that moves/slides depending on which tab you click on.

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Comment: looing for tab slider or just image slider?

Comment: just that triangle type-sliding.

Answer (score 1):

Some call it the "Content slider". There's quite many tutorials on the subject and here's few links to move you forwards:

- [13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)
- [25 Very Detailed jQuery Image and Content Slider Tutorials](http://designbeep.com/2010/05/13/25-very-detailed-jquery-image-and-content-slider-tutorials/)
- [Lightest jquery content slider ever – 380 bytes](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good guide, going over the main principles involved.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

Comment: Thanks but i meant just the triangle that movies, not the tabs themselves. :o)

Comment: All that is happening here, is that he is increasing the margin, on the css for the triangle. It is the same principles, applied to a different object - In your case, you would want to run a loop, which increases of decreases the triangle margin by 1. Giving it the slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a slider, its just a tabbed layout.

You can see the JS source at: http://www.adamscrap.com/js/switches.js

Comment: Correct but it slides to its location and i can not seem to find how that is done. I thought it was jQuery but even with that on the page it doesn't "slide"

Answer (score 0):

he has used [this](http://www.adamscrap.com/js/switches.js) function to move the triangle.

just look at it and u will find how simple it is!

Comment: Correct but it slides to its location and i can not seem to find how that is done. I thought it was jQuery but even with that on the page it doesn't "slide"

Comment: i suppose that u havent used firebug before. use it to find out where he has called the function and for which elements.